# AngularJs envia un OPTIONS por cada petición al backend

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, spring-security

Estoy haciendo una aplicación web para la tesis usando AngularJs v1.7.2 y Spring Boot y estoy teniendo problemas con los servicios web. Al hacer un llamado `POST` me hace dos peticiones una por `OPTIONS` y otra por `POST`, el problema es que me crea doble en mi base de datos ya que se hacen 2 peticiones idénticas. Ya revisé en mi frontend y no estoy llamando doble. También he probado un par de cosas en el frontend y en el backend y no ha funcionado. La seguridad del backend es con Srping Security que filtra cada petición para comprobar el token de autenticación y luego le pasa la petición a los `RestControllers`.

```js
//FRONTEND


//contante
app.constant('$backendConection', {
    server_ip: '192.168.1.101',
    port: '8080'
});     

//config
//Para poder enviar el token en el header
    jwtOptionsProvider.config({
        tokenGetter: function () {
            return localStorage.getItem('jwt');
        },
        whiteListedDomains: [$backendConection.server_ip]//el dominio que esta esperando al token

    });
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('jwtInterceptor');

//factory
  function save(data) {
        return $http({
            url: 'http://' + $backendConection.server_ip + ':' + $backendConection.port + '/news',
            method: 'POST',
            data: data,
            skipAuthorization: false //para enviar el token de autenticación
        });
    }

//En el controller

$scope.newss = {};
$scope.newss.title = 'mi titulo';
$scope.newss.text = 'mi texto';
$listNewsService.save($scope.newss).then(function (response) {
  var toast = $mdToast.simple().content('La noticia ha sido creada').position('bottom right');
  $mdToast.show(toast);
   $mdDialog.hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>
```

//Backend

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSecurityConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;


    @Bean
    public JwtAuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new JwtAuthTokenFilter();
    }

    //1 Cuanda arranca
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
     logger.info("configure-> authenticationManagerBuilder finished");
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    //2 Cuando arranca
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().
                authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,
                        "/",
                       "/*.html",
                        "/favicon.ico",
                        "/assets/**",
                        "/components/**",
                        "/**/*.html",
                        "/**/*.css",
                        "/**/*.js").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

//Controller

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
@PostMapping(value = "/news", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity save(@RequestBody News news) {
    if (this.newsService.save(news))
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
    else
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

Comment: Agrega el código del front end (donde haces el llamado) y el backend (método donde se procesa ese llamado) sino es muy difícil, por no decir imposible saber cual es tu problema..

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que se duplica en la base de datos? ¿Qué URL usas para cargar tus estáticos (la aplicación AngularJS) y cuál usas para hacer las llamadas REST? ¿Es el mismo puerto?

Comment: Por ejemplo yo tengo hago una peticion POST para añadir noticias y como por cada petición me hace otra de tipo OPTIONS pues me llega el backend 2 peticiones identicas y me crea 2 noticias identicas. Todo empezo cuando cambié en angularjs la url, de localhost al ip de la pc, para poder probarlo desde otras pc y moviles. de hecho el error solo ocurre desde el movil y usando google chrome. Siempre uso el mismo puerto 8080. voy a poner los codigos

Comment: Pero la aplicación (los ficheros JS) se sirven también desde el puerto 8080?

Comment: si pq yo primero tenia el forntend y el backend en proyectos distintos pero al final como soy yo solo pues puse el frontend en los ficheros static de spring boot asi que siempre es el puerto 8080.

Comment: La aplicación es una biblioteca 2.0, tiene una red social y un sistema de recomendación. Yo uso POST en varias ocaciones para añadir comentarios, hacer recomendación, login etc, pero solo me falla en añadir noticias y solo tengo este error cuando uso la app desde el movil por el navegador que sea, primero pense que solo era con chrome pero con firefox igual. lo otro es que no sucede siempre tengo que añadir añadir varias veeces y a veces me hace 2 peticiones de añadir por eso me añade 2.

Comment: puerto en el backend: configurado en el archivo properties

Comment: server.port=8080